# Phone Wifi Speed Test Slower Than Laptop

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, performance, internet-speed

Why is it that my phone gives a download speed of 100 mbps but my computer gives 330 mbps for the same wifi network?

Phone is on airplane mode so just wifi.

Answer (score 1):

There is likely better WIFI hardware (in terms of speed) in your computer.  This makes sense as computers are more likely to take advantage of more bandwidth, and have more space for antenna.

In order to get high speed, you need multiple antennas, and also space to separate them.  These are big asks for phones, which generally don't need as much data as laptops as they are supporting a smaller screen.   Similarly (but only slightly relevant here), the limits of batteries are more pronounced on phones, so they will often trade speed for battery life - and download speed may be a slight casualty of these decisions)

Comment: I have similar problem: WAN speed is around 50Mbps. If I connect phone to local wifi 5GHz I get almost that speed in test, but if I connect it to 2.4GHz it is less then half! It doesn't seem to happen on laptop and test results seem to be the same regardless of which wifi band it is connected to! I am just few meters from the router and phone has all the bars, so how can it be so much slower? Wifi info on the phone while connected to this 2.4GHz shows 86Mbps speed!

Comment: @Vitas what model cellphone, what model router?

Comment: I don't think it matters because it behaves the same on Vodafone internet with Huawei router tested on phones Galaxy S10 and OnePlus Nord 2 5G. Now I have recently changed ISP to O2 with Zyxel router and it's THE SAME! Both phones show hundreds of Mbps wifi speed but rychlost.cz app internet speed test is less then half on 2.4GHz then on 5GHz